# JavaScript closure problem please explain

Tags: javascript

This is a function taken from Pro JavaScript techniques that I'm trying to understand, but don't. The purpose of the function is to slowly reveal a hidden element by increasing its height over a matter of one second. The comments in the code are provided by the author of the book. I don't understand anything starting from where the author says in a comment "a closure to make sure we have the right 'i'.

Could you please explain in as much detail as possible

a) how does this closure work in this function. I.e. how does it make sure that it has the right 'i' and what in the code makes that important.

b) why is there a comma near the end of the program after elem in the code `elem,.style.height`

c) what is the purpose of this part of the code ( pos + 1) * 10). How does it work with the setTimeout function?

```
function slideDown(elem) {
  //start the slide down at 0
  elem.style.height = '0px';

    //Show the element, but can`t see it because height is 0
   show(elem);

    //find the full potential height of the element
    var h = fullHeight(elem);

   //We`re going to do a 20 frame animation that takes place over one second
   for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i +=5 ) {
         //a closure to make sure that we have the right 'i'
         (function() {
           var pos = i;

          //set the timeout to occur at the specified time in the future
          setTimeout(function() {

            //set the new height of the element
             elem,.style.height = (pos/100) * h) + "px";

         }, ( pos + 1) * 10);
       })();
     }
}
```

Comment: The `,` is a typo. It should read `elem.style.height = `. Additionally, also on that line, there is one more closing parenthesis than there are opening ones, which will cause a syntax error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) This is essential because of the `setTimeout()` call. Since `setTimeout()` is, logically, a sleeping thread, it could be called after the next loop iteration, `i` could be a different value by the time the body of `setTimeout()` is invoked. "Saving" the `i` as `pos` fixes this potential issue, and protects the value of `i` in case it is changed in the meantime. Now, the value of `pos` is completely determined in advanced and is not subject to being changed by the main thread (the loop that is incrementing `i`).

b) No idea, looks like a typo. **Edit:** yes it is a typo. There you go.

c) It ensures that the body of `setTimeout` is called at a future time proportional to the value of `i`. Think about it; if every call was `setTimeout(..., 10)`, then everything would start in 10ms but still be executed at whatever speed the loop was executed at. Adding `pos` as a factor in this value "slows down" the execution of the future `setTimeout` calls. As in the comments, it ensures that the future `setTimeout()` invocations occur at a rate of 20 times per second (creating a 20FPS animation effect)

Comment: Great answer. I would like to add that it's a bit funny that this code is from a "pro javascript techniques" book, since the code is very inefficient. Creating 100 anonymous functions on the fly and executing them and adding a new timer for every single frame.. That's just crazy.. You'll never get a smooth animation out of that.

Comment: It's not efficient, but it is instructive in the sense that it lumps a bunch of concepts into a small piece of code. But yes, agreed, and also not very "pro" to contain typos...

Comment: @arnorhs Also it is worth mentioning that that loop is only creating 20anon functions and not 100.

Comment: thank you. I understand the need to slow down the execution but can you explain in more detail how adding pos does that? Does it slow it down because it has to wait for pos to be set after each run through the loop? And what is the significance of using pos+1. After the first run through the loop, pos=5. So pos+1 * 10 = 60.

Comment: `pos` grows as the loop iterates; that is, it's larger on the 2nd iteration than it is on the first. Remember, `pos` is the value of i at that point on the loop. So the first call will be invoked in 10ms for `pos = 0`. Second call happens in 20ms for `pos = 1`. If pos were not a variable in the timeout, then the first call would happen in 10ms, the second in 11ms, the third in 12ms, and so on, so the spacing wouldn't be correct. Work it out on paper setting `pos` to `0,1,2,3...` and it'll become clearer.

Comment: @Travis, but there never is pos=1. The second call happens for pos=5, and 5 + 1 = 6.  6 * 10 = 60. In light of that, can you please explain how, as you say, second call happens in 20ms for pos = 1.

Comment: sorry, then repeat what I said for pos = 5,10,15, and so on. it's the same concept with different numbers. You have the formula, which is `(pos+1)*10`

Comment: but wait, what is the syntax () doing in near the end in the line: })();

Comment: Thanks @Quintin, you're right. However I forgot to mention that it's actually creating two anonymous functions in each loop run - one for the closure and one for the timer. 

@mjmitche it's calling the closure. If you look closely the function is wrapped within parenthesis. It's just a way to call it and define it at the same time, without creating a named variable.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a proper closure defining a correct value of `i` where you think.. You have it almost built though.. Try this..

```
   (function(index) {
       var pos = index;

      //set the timeout to occur at the specified time in the future
      setTimeout(function() {

        //set the new height of the element
         elem.style.height = ((pos/100) * h) + "px";

     }, (pos + 1) * 10);
   })(i);
```

By passing `i` as a parameter to the function it will pass the current value in the execution and `index` will have the properly assigned value.

**EDIT**

Wanted to add this [good explanataion of closures and references in javascript](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.closures).

Comment: What actual difference does it make? the pos local variable is captured inside the closure wether or not you pass it as an argument no?

Comment: @ChrisR no, it is assigned a reference in current scope of the `i` variable, which will have the last value as of the last interation by time of the execution. So in essence when the function gets executed (all of them) there will be a bunch of variables in the anonymous functions that all reference the `i` variable (which will be at it's last iteration).

Comment: Thank you. Is it true that after the second run through the for loop, pos =5? so at the bottom, you have (5 + 1) *10.  What does this number 60 represent and how does it get used. Is it passed as an argument to setTimeout?

Comment: @mjmitche Correct it is the timeout portion of `setTimeout`, it will represent a millisecond value. Basically ensuring a grading animation by multiplying the index instead of just adding and having all the timeouts occur in close succession. You can see some documentation on `setTimeout` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout

Answer (score 1):

a) as you're iterating over `i`, and it pretends to be used in a callback, when the callback is called, the value of `i` will be the last `i` reached. Creating a closure, you create a copy of i (because it's a primitive type), with another position in memory. Doing this, when the callback is called, it will use the closure's instance.

The difference is that, in memory, you have only one `i`, but N instances of `pos` (and N closure scopes), so when the `setTimeout` callback starts, it will be referencing to the specific scope of the closure used to define it.

b) Sounds like a typo.

c) It's the time in milliseconds of delay. In the algorithm, it seems like it will fire the resize of the first element at 10 miliseconds, the second one at 20, and so on.

This functions works as this: `setTimeout(callback, milliseconds)`, and a function could be anonymous, so `setTimeout(function() { ... }, 10)`is a valid syntax.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

c) this code fires off a series of setTimeout calls which create the animation. The ( pos + 1) * 10 code ensures that each setTimeout happens a little later than the one before it, thereby staggering each call which is what makes the animation happen.

Comment: thank you. can you explain how the pos + 1 works exactly. For example, if I understand correctly, after first run through of the for loop (i=0 i<100 i+=5), pos =5. Therefor, in (pos + 1) * 10 = 60?? But 60 what? 60 seconds? and how does that delay set timeout? Also is setTimeout a predefined function?

Comment: it's 60 milliseconds. it tells setTimeout how long to wait before executing the callback function. setTimeout is a function provided by the javascript engine in the browser. Not sure if it is part of the standatd ECMAScript and would be available in other host environments, or if its native to browsers only.